# Correlating specific heat (Cp) of a substance with other substance on the basis of similar physio-chemical properties

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, theoretical-chemistry, software

I am modelling $\ce{H2O2}$ decomposition in ANSYS Chemkin-Pro and I have difficulty finding $C_p$ (specific heat at constant pressure) for liquid $\ce{H2O2}$ for various temperature ranges.

My ultimate aim is to find the 14 NASA polynomial coefficients so that I can input them in Chemkin-Pro. For that I need a range of $C_p$ *vs* $T$ data, so that I can fit the data and find the coefficients.

So I was wondering whether we can correlate specific heat of $\ce{H2O2(l)}$ with some other species on basis of same physio-chemical properties?

If yes, then I can try finding $C_p$ *vs* $T$ data for those other species. I know that this will cause some error but that is better than having no data at all.

I don't have a background in physical chemistry, so if anybody can help, it will be really helpful for me.